# RSpec: "expect with" function called from the wrong module when used with fastlane

Tags: ruby, rspec, fastlane

I want to use RSpec together with fastlane and did the setup suggested by RSpec. I want to check in my tests if a function is called with the correct parameters. I used the example code from here to check exactly this:
https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-2/docs/setting-constraints/matching-arguments

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rspec'

RSpec.describe "Constraining a message expectation using with" do
  let(:dbl) { double }
  before { expect(dbl).to receive(:foo).with(1, anything, /bar/) }


  it "passes when the args match" do
    dbl.foo(1, nil, "barn")
  end

  it "fails when the args do not match" do
    dbl.foo(1, nil, "other")
  end
end
```

When I execute this using 'rspec', this is fine. No errors and I get the expected result.

However if I load the fastlane actions in my spec_helper.rb file like this

```
$LOAD_PATH.unshift File.expand_path('..', __dir__)

module SpecHelper
end

require 'fastlane'

Fastlane.load_actions
Fastlane.plugin_manager.load_plugins
```

I suddenly get the following error:

```
Constraining a message expectation using with passes when the args match
 Failure/Error: before { expect(dbl).to receive(:foo).with(1, anything, /bar/) }

 ArgumentError:
   wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 0..1)
 # /Users/philip.otto/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/facets-3.1.0/lib/core/facets/kernel/with.rb:15:in `with'
 # ./spec/iz_create_release_branch_spec.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

So the problem seems to be that the wrong function 'with' is taken from another module in facets/kernel/with.rb instead of correctly from the rspec_mocks files.

How can I make sure the right function is called? Why is this wrong function called in the first place?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I believe `before { expect(dbl).to receive(:foo).with(1, anything, /bar/) }` should be `before { allow(dbl).to receive(:foo).with(1, anything, /bar/) }`

Comment: Alex's suggestion may be the answer. I'm used to putting the expects in the examples (i.e https://github.com/lyndsey-ferguson/fastlane-plugin-test_center/blob/master/spec/collate_html_reports_spec.rb#L59).

I like how this website taught me Rspec: https://relishapp.com/rspec

Comment: @AlexGolubenko. Thanks for your input! The code is 100% copied from the rspec page. Allow and expect are two different things. The issue is that the 'with' function gets overriden by the facets gem that we use. We are currently narrowing down the issue.

Comment: No problems :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be not an issue with fastlane but rather with a dependency that we add to our project. The dependency is called *facets* and it includes [a file](https://github.com/rubyworks/facets/blob/39ca41195df3f005af5c94cba302607cf59867c7/lib/core/facets/kernel/with.rb) that globally overrides every function called *with*.

I reported it on their GitHub and I am now waiting for their answer.
[Link to report](https://github.com/rubyworks/facets/issues/290)